# How to use TimedRotatingFileHandler without backup? every day overwrite existed log file?

Tags: python, logging

I'm running a certain Python code for days, every day I want **one** .log file without backup, basically, let's say I overwrite bt releasing everything and start again. I used [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) but it would save previous logs, is there any other way than making a timer thread to remove any extra log file?

Comment: Specify `backup=1` when you make an instance if you can live with one previous log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with just one backup file, specify `...,backupCount=1,...` when you make an instance.

Otherwise you can subclass [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f7b0259d0d243a71d79a3fda9ec7aad4306513eb/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L191) and override its `getFilesToDelete` method.

```
class MyRFH(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    """
    Handler for logging to a file, rotating the log file at certain timed
    intervals.

    If backupCount is > 0, when rollover is done, ALL previous logs are deleted.
    """
    def getFilesToDelete(self):
        """
        Determine the files to delete when rolling over.
        Will NOT keep any backup files.
        Modified from Standard Library Class
        """
        dirName, baseName = os.path.split(self.baseFilename)
        fileNames = os.listdir(dirName)
        result = []
        prefix = baseName + "."
        plen = len(prefix)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if fileName[:plen] == prefix:
                suffix = fileName[plen:]
                if self.extMatch.match(suffix):
                    result.append(os.path.join(dirName, fileName))
        if self.backupCount == 0:
            result = []
##        if len(result) < self.backupCount:
##            result = []
##        else:
##            result.sort()
##            result = result[:len(result) - self.backupCount]
        return result
```

---

Adapting an example from the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-file-rotation)

```
import logging, time, glob,sys,os
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

class MyRFH(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    """
    Handler for logging to a file, rotating the log file at certain timed
    intervals.

    If backupCount is > 0, when rollover is done, ALL previous logs are deleted.
    """
    def getFilesToDelete(self):
        """
        Determine the files to delete when rolling over.
        Will NOT keep any backup files.
        Modified from Standard Library Class
        """
        dirName, baseName = os.path.split(self.baseFilename)
        fileNames = os.listdir(dirName)
        result = []
        prefix = baseName + "."
        plen = len(prefix)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if fileName[:plen] == prefix:
                suffix = fileName[plen:]
                if self.extMatch.match(suffix):
                    result.append(os.path.join(dirName, fileName))
        if self.backupCount == 0:
            result = []
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotatingfile_example'

    # Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
    my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
    my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Add the log message handler to the logger
    handler = MyRFH(LOG_FILENAME, when='s', interval=5, backupCount=1)

    my_logger.addHandler(handler)

    # Log some messages
    for i in range(200):
        my_logger.debug('i = %d' % i)
        time.sleep(.1)

    # See what files are created
    logfiles = glob.glob('%s*' % LOG_FILENAME)

    for filename in logfiles:
        print(filename)
```